# dozer upgrade to mapstruct

Tags: java, dozer, mapstruct

Im using [dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) in my app for bean to bean mapping...due to its vulnerabilities I want to upgrade to mapstruct

In dozer we had one mapper function for bean to bean mapping and it doing mapping for all different instance.

In MapStruct I m not able to achieve with same one method.

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.MappingException;

/**
 * Factory for creating DTO objects based on the object identifier that
 * is passed to the object creation method.
 */
public class RetrieveChangeSetObjectDtoFactory {
    private Map<String, String> objectIdentifiers;  
    private DozerBeanMapper beanMapper;

    public Object createDto(String objectIdentifier, Persistence srcObject) throws MappingException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String className = objectIdentifiers.get(objectIdentifier);

        if (className == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return beanMapper.map(srcObject, Class.forName(className));
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the object identifiers map, maps the domain objects to their associated DTO classes.
     * 
     * @param objectIdentifiers object identifiers map
     */
    public void setObjectIdentifiers(Map<String, String> objectIdentifiers) {
        this.objectIdentifiers = objectIdentifiers;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the bean mapper.
     * 
     * @param beanMapper bean mapper (dozer)
     */
    public void setBeanMapper(DozerBeanMapper beanMapper) {
        this.beanMapper = beanMapper;
    }
}
```

`beanmapper.map` is mapping objects for me...objects getting mapped through hashmap spring bean loading

want to have same one method for mapping all objects stored in hashmap

[image]

This is my Spring Dozer bean

Comment: Another reason to move to MapStuct (security is still a good reason) is that Dozer is known to have poor performances compared to other mapping libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important difference between MapStruct and Dozer is that MapStruct is an annotation processor tool, which means it generates code. You will have to create interfaces / mappings that will generate the mapping code you need.

MapStruct does not have a single entry point that does generic mapping. However, you can implement something like that on your own side if you want to.

You would need a base interface that all your mappers will implement

```
public interface BaseMapper<S, T> {

    T toDto(S source);

    S toEntity(T target);
}
```

You will then need to implement your `RetrieveChangeSetObjectDtoFactory` in a slightly different way.

```
public class RetrieveChangeSetObjectDtoFactory {

    private Map<Class<?>, Map<Class<?>, BaseMapper<?, ?>>> entityDtoMappers = new HashMap<>();

    public <S, T> Object createDto(Class<S> entityClass, Class<T> dtoClass, S source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return getMapper(entityClass, dtoClass).toDto(source);
    }

    public <S, T> Object createSource(Class<S> entityClass, Class<T> dtoClass, T dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return getMapper(entityClass, dtoClass).toEntity(dto);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <S, T> BaseMapper<S, T> getMapper(Class<S> entityClass, Class<T> dtoClass) {
        // appropriate checks
        return (BaseMapper<S, T>) entityDtoMappers.get(entityClass).get(dtoClass);
    }

    public <S, T> void registerMapper(Class<S> entityClass, Class<T> dtoClass, BaseMapper<S, T> mapper) {
        entityDtoMappers.computeIfAbsent(entityClass, key -> new HashMap<>()).put(dtoClass, mapper);
    }
}
```

However, I would recommend to just inject the mappers you need them instead of doing something so generic.